# How can I get a value by it self using php from a database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I am trying to access `firstname` by it self. I have the code below put together:

```html
<?php
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM guests WHERE option = $option";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "You Are " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
?>
```

It gives me `You are Bob Testing.` I need to convert them to self variable so I can use them anywhere. Like `$row["firstname"] = $firstname;` so then I could `echo $firstname;` But it won't work if I use `$row["firstname"] = $firstname;`

I think the issue is somewhere in how I form the result `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` Can I say something else here so then I could just use say `$row["firstname"] = $firstname;` and use like `echo $firstname;`?  Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you do `$firstname = $row['firstname']` if you're setting a variable? (if that's not what you're trying to do tell me).

Comment: If you do `$row['firstname'] = $firstname;`, you're setting `$row['firstname']` AS `$firstname`, which I'm guessing isn't what you're trying to do.

Comment: set a variable for each row's columns in the `while` loop. Do the inverse of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @k97513 yeah but I didn't realize I had to put it `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { HERE }`  and I was trying to do `$row["firstname"] = $firstname;` but in reality I needed `$firstname = $row['firstname']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, if this is your actual code, it's missing a few closing braces.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "You Are " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    } // this one was missing

} // as was this one
```

Now, assign a variable "to" the row(s) and not the other way around.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $first = $row["firstname"];
        $last = $row["lastname"];
    }
        echo "You are " . $first . " " . $last . "<br>";
}
```

However the above will only echo a single row, therefore you will need to place the echo "inside" the `while` loop in order to echo all the rows in your table:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $first = $row["firstname"];
        $last = $row["lastname"];

        echo "You are " . $first . " " . $last . "<br>";
    }

}
```

---

Something about this though `WHERE option = $option";`

If `$option` is a string, it will need to be quoted:

```
WHERE option = '$option'";
```

otherwise, MySQL will see that as a syntax error. Check for errors on your query:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

It will also be prone to an SQL injection, therefore it is best you use a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Seeing you may be new to working with MySQL, it's best to learn about protecting yourself against SQL injection. Here is a good article about it on Stack:

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Remember multiple results will overwrite it each time so `$first` and `$last` will only ever be the last record extracted from the database.

Comment: @Doug yes and that's why I made an additional edit, placing the echo inside the `while` loop. I wanted to show the OP the difference between both.

Comment: Beat me to it! Must have submitted my comment as you made the update

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  You do realize this is just a snippet of my code.  I needed help how to get the `$firstname` by it self. Little did I know you have to put it inside `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { HERE }` Thanks so much. As for `$option` it's already declared a bit higher up(code I didn't paste.) Thanks you help me a lot.

Comment: And I didn't need the `loop` because based on the goal I'm trying to achieve here there will only ever be one result for `WHERE option = $option`